# the trait `std::ops::Fn<()>` is not implemented for [closure ...] but only with a binding from the outer scope

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {

    let s = Some("xyz".to_string());  //compiler error

    let foo = Box::new(|| s) as Box<Fn() -> Option<String>>;  //ok

    let bar = Box::new(|| Some("xyz".to_string())) as Box<Fn() -> Option<String>>;

    println!("{:?}", foo());
    println!("{:?}", bar());
}
```

gives the error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[closure@src/main.rs:5:24: 5:28 s:std::option::Option<std::string::String>]: std::ops::Fn<()>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:5:15
  |
5 |     let foo = Box::new(|| s) as Box<Fn() -> Option<String>>;
  |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::ops::Fn<()>` is not implemented for `[closure@src/main.rs:5:24: 5:28 s:std::option::Option<std::string::String>]`
  |
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `std::ops::Fn() -> std::option::Option<std::string::String>`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

The docs for [Trait std::ops::Fn](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html) state:

> Fn is implemented automatically by closures which only take immutable references to captured variables or don't capture anything at all,

`s` isn't mutable, but it's not a reference and I'm moving it.

If I call `s.clone()` the compiler error goes away, but in my real case I want to avoid that.

Same error if I use `FnMut`   `FnOnce` complains about not knowing the size, even though it is Boxed.

Is there a way I can make this work with moved data?

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=98709024e37385428e0600a467f62b84&version=undefined)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this was allowed, what would happen the second time the closure was called? Remember, the first time the closure is called, it moves `s`, so `s` now has no valid value.

There are a few ways to make this work, depending on what you need exactly.

1. Make the closure return a reference to the string instead.

   *Note:* We need to write out `'a` explicitly on the right-hand side of the `as` cast expression, otherwise the compiler gives an error. I don't think we can write a correct lifetime without introducing an intermediate function (`make_foo` here).

   ```
   fn make_foo<'a>(s: &'a Option<String>) -> Box<Fn() -> Option<&'a str> + 'a> {
       Box::new(move || s.as_ref().map(|s| &**s)) as Box<Fn() -> Option<&'a str> + 'a>
   }

   fn main() {
       let s = Some("xyz".to_string());
       let foo = make_foo(&s);

       println!("{:?}", foo());
   }
   ```
2. Use <del>[`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html)</del> [`FnBox`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.23.0/std/boxed/trait.FnBox.html) instead of `Fn`. `FnOnce` closures can move, but can be called at most once. Since we can't call a `Box<FnOnce()>` as of Rust 1.23.0, we need to use `Box<FnBox()>`.

   ```
   #![feature(fnbox)]

   use std::boxed::FnBox;

   fn main() {
       let s = Some("xyz".to_string());
       let foo = Box::new(|| s) as Box<FnBox() -> Option<String>>;

       println!("{:?}", foo());
   }
   ```

However, since `FnBox` is unstable, you can only use it with a nightly compiler. If you want to support stable compilers, you can use the `BoxFnOnce` type defined in the [`boxfnonce` crate](https://crates.io/crates/boxfnonce) instead (though you need to explicitly call the closure as `x.call()`; `x()` won't work).